# Conversion of a string coming as parameter in date with time zone format in oracle 9i

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle9i

My requirement is to pass the date in the following format as parameter '2014-07-11T11:22:21.031+03:00' .
Then convert it to the date format with time stamp and then insert it into a table.
I have been trying and getting the following errors :-

```
SQL> SELECT TO_DATE('2014-07-11 11:22:21.031','YYYY-MM-DD H24:MI:SS.FFF')  FROM DUAL;
SELECT TO_DATE('2014-07-11 11:22:21.031','YYYY-MM-DD H24:MI:SS.FFF')  FROM DUAL
                                         *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01821: date format not recognized


SQL>

SQL> SELECT TO_TIMESTAMP('2014-07-11 11:22:21.031','YYYY-MM-DD H24:MI:SS.FFF') FROM DUAL;
SELECT TO_TIMESTAMP('2014-07-11 11:22:21.031','YYYY-MM-DD H24:MI:SS.FFF') FROM DUAL
                                              *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01821: date format not recognized


SQL>

SQL> SELECT TO_CHAR('2014-07-11 11:22:21.031','YYYY-MM-DD H24:MI:SS.FFF') FROM DUAL;
SELECT TO_CHAR('2014-07-11 11:22:21.031','YYYY-MM-DD H24:MI:SS.FFF') FROM DUAL
               *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01722: invalid number
```

What if I the parameter date has the format  '2014_07_11T11:22:21.031_03:00' ?

Comment: `H24` Should be `HH24` The Last `SELECT` is throwing error due to implicit date conversion of your string..

Comment: There are two errors, `H24` and `FFF`. It should be `HH24` and `FF`

Answer (score 2):

To answer your question specifically, **you have two mistakes, 'H24' and 'FFF'. I changed it to 'HH24' and 'FF' :**

```
SQL> SELECT TO_TIMESTAMP('2014-07-11 11:22:21.031','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF') FROM DUAL;

TO_TIMESTAMP('2014-07-1111:22:21.031','YYYY-MM-DDHH24:MI:SS.FF')
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
11-JUL-14 11.22.21.031000000 AM
```

Regarding your three attempts :

- You can't use `to_date` here, since it **cannot hold fractions of a
  second**.
- You were going in correct direction, just that you did two things
  wrong as I already mentioned above.
- `to_char`? Why? It is used to display the date or timestamp in the
  required format using proper format mask.

**Another example :**  To set the required format at session level

```
SQL> ALTER SESSION SET nls_timestamp_tz_format = 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS.FF TZH:TZM';

Session altered.

SQL> SELECT TO_TIMESTAMP('11-SEP-2014 17:01:30.034000','DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS.FF') FROM DUAL
  2  /

TO_TIMESTAMP('11-SEP-201417:01:30.034000','DD-MON-YYYYHH24:MI:SS.FF')
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
11-SEP-14 05.01.30.034000000 PM

SQL>
```

Answer (score 1):

`H24` Should be `HH24` The Last `SELECT` is throwing error due to implicit date conversion of your string.. The Format you need to use is

```
YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SSxFF
```

The final Query would be

```
SELECT TO_TIMESTAMP('2014-07-11 11:22:21.031','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SSxFF') FROM DUAL;
```

OR `TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ` give you exactly what you look for!

```
SELECT TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ('2014-07-11 11:22:21.031 +03:00','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SSxFF TZH:TZM') FROM DUAL;
```

Finally, without you have ANSI Date or predefined Date , never use`TO_CHAR()` for which Oracle applies implicit date conversion first and only then the `TO_CHAR()` will be performed. So, for your last Query '2014-07-11 11:22:21.031' was implicitly attempted to be converted as Date using session's `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` and it failed with invalid number.